How to get only directory from URI
A URL with parameters is passed to the URI variable.
The protocol and domain may be https://example.com or localhost:xxxxxx.
In either case, the subsequent directory and file names are the same.
In this case, is there a way to get it only from the directory?
example:
 final uri = Uri.parse("localhost:XXXX/category1/category2/?id=AAAA")

 // or it might be 

 final uri = Uri.parse("https://example.com/category1/category2/?id=AAAA")


 final result = doMagic(uri); // this is what I ask
 print(result); // category1/category2/?id=AAAA



For this:
final uri = Uri.parse("https://example.com/category1/category2/?id=AAAA");

you can get:
final path = uri.path; // '/category1/category2/'
final query = uri.query; // 'id=AAAA'

